# Pyspark retain only distinct (drop all duplicates)

Tags: join, pyspark, duplicates

After joining two dataframes (which have their own ID's) I have some duplicates (repeated ID's from both sources)
I want to drop **all** rows that are duplicates on either ID (so not retain a single occurrence of a duplicate)

I can group by the first ID, do a count and filter for count ==1, then repeat that for the second ID, then inner join these outputs back to the original joined dataframe - but this feels a bit long.

Is there a simpler method like dropDuplicates() but where none of the duplicates are left behind?

I see pandas has an option not to keep the first duplicate df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'C'], keep=False)

Comment: window_df1 = Window.partitionBy("ID1") and window_df2 = Window.partitionBy("ID2")  I can then add columns with counts of both  ID's over the windows. Then filter to only counts of 1. Is partitionBy using an almost unique value  going to be inefficient?

Answer (score 4):

### dropDuplicates()

According to the official [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates).

> Return a new DataFrame with duplicate rows removed, optionally only
>   considering certain columns.

To drop duplicates considering all columns:

```
df.dropDuplicates()
```

If want to drop duplicates from certain column

```
df.dropDuplicate(subset=col_name)
```

For multiple columns:

```
df.dropDuplicates(subset=[col_name1, col_name2])
```

#### Edit for the comment

```
df =  df.agg(criteria_col).agg(sum(lit(1)).alias('freq'))

df = df.filter(col('freq')=1)
```

Comment: I've used df.dropDuplicate(subset=col_name) but I believe this retains the row which is the first in the set of duplicates. I want my dataframe after joining to only contain the 1-1 links between the ID's of the contributing dataframes