# drop all instances of duplicates in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried searching for this but the closest I could come to was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322699/pyspark-retain-only-distinct-drop-all-duplicates/51323346). But it did not give me what I wanted.
I want to drop all instances of duplicates in a dataframe.
For example, if I have a data frame

```
   Col1   Col2   Col3
   Alice  Girl   April
   Jean   Boy    Aug
   Jean   Boy    Sept
```

I want to remove **all** duplicate based on Col1 and Col2 so that I get

```
  Col1   Col2  Col3
  Alice  Girl  April
```

Is there any way to do this?

Also if I have a large number of columns like so:

```
   Col1   Col2   Col3  .... Col n
   Alice  Girl   April .... Apple
   Jean   Boy    Aug   .... Orange
   Jean   Boy    Sept  .... Banana
```

How would I group by only Col1 and Col2 but still keep the remaining columns?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
# Sample Dataframe
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ["Alice", "Girl","April"],
   ["Jean","Boy", "Aug"],
   ["Jean","Boy","Sept"]
], 
    ["Col1","Col2", "Col3"])

# Group by on required column and select rows where count is 1.
df2 = (df
       .groupBy(["col1", "col2"])
       .agg(
           F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('count'), 
           F.max("col3").alias("col3")).where("count = 1")).drop("count")

df2.show(10, False)
```

Output:

```
+-----+----+-----+
|col1 |col2|col3 |
+-----+----+-----+
|Alice|Girl|April|
+-----+----+-----+
```

### Response to the edited version

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ["Alice", "Girl","April", "April"],
    ["Jean","Boy", "Aug", "XYZ"],
    ["Jean","Boy","Sept", "IamBatman"]
], 
    ["col1","col2", "col3", "newcol"])

groupingcols = ["col1", "col2"]
othercolumns = [F.max(col).alias(col) for col in df.columns if col not in groupingcols]

df2 = (df
       .groupBy(groupingcols)
       .agg(F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('count'), *othercolumns)
       .where("count = 1")
       .drop("count"))

df2.show(10, False)
```

Output:

```
+-----+----+-----+------+
|col1 |col2|col3 |newcol|
+-----+----+-----+------+
|Alice|Girl|April|April |
+-----+----+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Could you explain why you use the F.max? Cant I just filter by the `where("count = 1")` ?

Comment: When you are applying grouping, all the columns that you want in the resultant `dataframe` must have an aggregation applied to them otherwise they will get dropped from the resultant `dataframe`. Hence a single where clause would drop `col3`.

Please accept the answer if that's what you wanted. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you @Sunny Shukla. I have accepted your answer since , in fairness, it answers the specific question in the example I posted. However my actual dataframe contains many more columns like Col3. Is there a way to keep all those columns after grouping without having aggregate all those extra columns?
I have updated my original post accordingly
Thank You

Comment: Updated another response to generalise the same, the grouping(in some sense would be needed to know the counts) and apply max to a single row column would return the same value so that should be okay. 

Another way would be to just group and get rows which have single rows and then `inner` join with the original dataset but this was we get it done in a single run.